# Angular 2: Dynamic Images

Tags: image, angular, binding

What's the best way to set an `img` tag in **Angular2**?

This doesn't work (and not because of the key):

```
<img src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location="{{property.lat}}, {{property.long}}"key=aiwefmboij234blahblah" />
```

How do we pass in the lat/long values into the `src` attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no need to close the " on the src attribute. if you close it, it will renderer like this:

```
<img src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=" 12.121212 , 13.31133 "&key=aiwefmboij234blahblah" />
```

Which is not a correct HTML;

One way to correctly do it:

```
<img src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location={{property.lat}},{{property.long}}&key=aiwefmboij234blahblah" />
```

Another way is to build the url on the component and assign it to a variable, then:

```
<img [src]="urlVariable" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight!  I followed your direction and rendered my streetview picture.  This might help a lot of folks because the documentation is a little light on this scenario, I think.